# How to dynamically change content in node project run through docker

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, dockerfile

I have an angularjs application, I'm running using docker.
The docker file looks like this:-

```
FROM node:6.2.2

RUN npm install --global gulp-cli && \
    npm install --global bower

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
COPY bower.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install && \
    bower install -F --allow-root --config.interactive=false
COPY . /usr/src/app

ENV GULP_COMMAND serve:dist

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c"]
CMD ["gulp $GULP_COMMAND"]
```

Now when I make any changes in say any html file, It doesn't dynamically loads up on the web page. I have to stop the container, remove it, build the image again, remove the earlier image and then restart the container from new image. Do I have to do this every time? (I'm new to docker, and I guess this issue is coz my source code is not put into volume, but I don't know how to do it using docker file)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are correct, you should use volumes for stuff like this. During development, give it the same volumes as the `COPY` directories. It'll override it with whatever is on your machine, no need to rebuild the image, or even restart the container. Perfect for development.

When actually baking your images for production, you remove the volumes, leave the `COPY` in, and you'll get a deterministic container. I would recommend you read through this article here: https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/.

In general, there are 3 ways to do volumes.

1. [Define them in your dockerfile using `VOLUME`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#volume).

   Personally, I've never done this. I don't really see the benefits of this against the other two methods. I believe it would be more common to do this when your volume is meant to act as a permanent data-store. Not so much when you're just trying to use your live dev environment.
2. [Define them when calling `docker run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#volume-shared-filesystems).

   ```
   docker run ... -v $(pwd)/src:/usr/src/app ...
   ```

   This is great, cause if your `COPY` in your dockerfile is `./src /usr/src/app` then it temporarily overrides the directory while running the image, but it's still there for deployment when you don't use `-v`.
3. [Use docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/).

   My personal recommendation. Docker compose massively simplifies running containers. For sake of simplicity just calls `docker run ...` but automates the arguments based on a given `docker-compose.yml` config.

   Create a `dev` service specifying the volumes you want to mount, other containers you want it linked to, etc. Then bring it up using `docker-compose up ...` or `docker-compose run ...` depending on what you need.

Smart use of volumes will DRAMATICALLY reduce your development cycle. Would really recommend looking into them.

Comment: Basically in my docker-compose file I tried volumes:
      - ./src:/usr/src/app/src, but the change is not reflecting

Comment: @ShubhamGupta what command are you running when starting up your container? Also what system are you running on? Volumes can have some strange behaviors depending on where you're running them. Are there any errors being printed?

Comment: I first ran docker-compose build, then used docker-compose up.  Im using mac. When I tried Volume : .:usr/src/app, it gave couldn't find local gulp-file. When I used Volume : ./src:usr/src/app/src. container ran, but didn't reflect change dynamically

Comment: Hmmm, without actually being able to run your configuration on your machine myself, I don't know how much help I could be. Are you sure you're looking in the right folder in the container?

Comment: Only thing I can think, is try to make a new compose project with a really simple test case (try bash in a basic ubuntu image, and changing a single text file.) If you can make a minimum, complete, verifiable example of this same behavior you might be able to get some help by posting it as a separate question here. If it does work, you can inspect the two containers and look for differences.

Comment: Things finally worked. Actually I was running application from release folder due to gulp serve:dist command. I changed that to gulp serve, and things worked. Thanks for the help! Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to rebuild every time the files change, since you only modify the files that are outside of the container. In order to apply the changes to the files IN the container, you need to rebuild the container.

Depending on the use case, you could either make the Docker Container dynamically load the files from another repository, or you could mount an external volume to use in the container, but there are some pitfalls associated with either solution.

Comment: What are the pitfalls if I mount an external volume in the container. And how can I mention that in Dockerfile itself?

Comment: well the pitfalls are that you lose deterministism in the container itself. one of the ideas of docker containers is that your image will always behave in the same way, independent of the envinronment its running in. usually volumes are only mounted to achieve persistence of data, if you have html files that are part of your application they should actually be baekd in the container

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep your container running as you add your files you could also use a variation.

1. Mount a volume to any other location e.g. /usr/src/staging.
2. While the container is running, if you need to copy new files into the container, copy them into the location of the mounted volume.
3. Run `docker exec -it <container-name> bash` to open a bash shell inside the running container.
4. Run a `cp /usr/src/staging/* /usr/src/app` command to copy all new files into the target folder.